# What's the meaning of a golden border around an open letter in Canada?

Tags: canada, symbols

Yesterday, a group of parliamentarians and former Canadian diplomats wrote a letter to Canadian Prime Minister Justin Trudeau, [urging the release of Huawei CFO Meng Wanzhou](https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/letter-release-meng-1.5625669).

The [letter](http://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/6956527/Letter-to-Prime-Minister.pdf) features the same inset gold border and black marker on each page. Coloured borders have carried special meaning in the past. For example, the black borders on [mourning stationery](https://www.shapell.org/historical-perspectives/curated-manuscripts/mourning-stationery/) indicated the author was in mourning, and American legislation is instantly recognizable from its thin red border. Does this choice of gold border and black page marker have any special significance in Canada or the Commonwealth? Why not just use a blank background?

[image: first page of letter]

Comment: It's a wedding invitation. https://www.hallmark.com/cards/note-cards-and-stationery/designed-stationery/gold-border-stationery-box-of-20-1499STN1121.html (I'm kidding, but I don't know of a diplomatic meaning otherwise.)

Comment: National Geographic? (also kidding)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any other instances of a border like this. It's important to remember that the rise of computer communications has rendered custom stationary obsolete (Microsoft Word can [easily add a colored border like this](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-colorful-border-word-29745.html)). The most I've been able to find is the occasional letterhead. The Canadian Chamber of Commerce has [several letters to ministers](http://www.chamber.ca/advocacy/letters-to-federal-ministers/) (including the Prime Minister of Canada) and none of them have a background.

## Why not just use a blank background?

It's still uncommon to do this. It stands out a bit more than a white background would.